# Trying to wait for one observable to emit/initialize before using pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, ng-bootstrap

I am using ngbtypeahead as an autocomplete search option, the user types something in, this typed value is emitted to a parent component which then makes a call to the server, the returned value (an Observeable) is then passed down back to the child.
 what I am trying to do is only emit with `switchMap` (the end of my pipe) once my `typeAhead` component receives `data` as `@input` from the parent component (the results to display as autocomplete options), the `data` is the result of a call to the server. Initially (before anything has been typed) `data` is null and therefore the `typeAhead` component has an undefined value for the `data`.
My issue is that the *first* time I type what seems to be happening is that the `pipe` is completing before before the `data` has been received by the typeAhead (child) component, this results in it displaying **no** autocomplete options. My code is below, the main question I have is what is wrong with my `handleTypeahead` function that is not emitting the typed values when I type into the autcomplete.

```
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, of} from "rxjs";
import {
  debounceTime,
  delayWhen,
  distinctUntilChanged, filter,
  last,
  map,
  mergeMap,
  switchMap,
  tap,
  withLatestFrom,
} from "rxjs/operators";
import {FilterService} from "@carebox/core";
import {ISearchCriteria} from "@carebox/core";
import {NgbTypeaheadSelectItemEvent} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

@Component({
  selector: 'core-ui-typeahead-filter',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  templateUrl: './typeahead-filter.component.html',
})
export class TypeaheadFilterComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() id: string;
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() caption: string;
  @Input() placeholder: string;
  @Input() cssClass: string;
  @Input() cssStyle: string;
  @Input() function: any;

  @Input() data: Observable<string[]>

  model: any;




  @Output() onTypeahead: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() onSelect: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();


  constructor() {
  }




  handleTypeahead = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    this.data.subscribe(
      (data) => {
        if (data) {
          return text$.pipe(
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            debounceTime(200),
            filter(term => term !== ''),
            tap((term) => console.log("handleTypeahead", term)),
            tap((term) => this.onTypeahead.emit(term)),
            /*map((term: string) => [])*/
            /*map((term: string) => term === '' ? [] : this.data)*/
            // withLatestFrom(this.data),
            switchMap(() => this.data)
          );
        }
      }
    )

  }
handleSelectItem(item) {
  this.onSelect.emit(item);
}

ngOnInit() {
  // this.data.subscribe()
}

}
```

Relevant template:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="label-filters" for="{{id}}">
  {{caption}}
</label>

  <input id="{{id}}"
         name="{{name}}"
         type="text"
         placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
         class="{{cssClass}}"
         style="{{cssStyle}}"
         autocomplete="off"
         [(ngModel)]="model"
         [ngbTypeahead]="handleTypeahead"
         (selectItem)="handleSelectItem($event.item)"
  >
</div>
```

one solution I have tried is simply to add in the `delay` operator with 500ms delay this works but is not elegant and has some other issue. There should be a way to explicitly wait for the @input value to come in.

Adding the relevant code in the parent component as well as the template:

```
 /* NctId Filter */
  public NctIdTypeahead(term: string) {
    this.model.NctIdList = [];

    if (!(term && term.length > 0)) {
      return;
    }

    this.searchCriteria.nctIdPrefix = term;
    this.searchCriteria.aggregateOn = 'nctid';
    this.filterService.GetNctIdFilterData(this.searchCriteria).pipe(
      last(),
      map((result: any) => {
        return result.nctid;
      })
    ).subscribe(id => this.NctIdList = of(id))

  }
```

As well as the template (of the parent):

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <core-ui-typeahead-filter
      id="NctIdFilter"
      caption="NCT ID"
      placeholder="Type to select NCT ID"
      i18n-placeholder="@@T-trials.trial_protocol_id_filter_placeholder"
      [data]="NctIdList"
      [cssClass]="'form-control'"
      (onTypeahead)="NctIdTypeahead($event)"
      (onSelect)="NctIdSelect($event)">
    </core-ui-typeahead-filter>
  </div>
```

Comment: It is a bit hard for me to follow what the problem is.  I'm pretty sure it is impossible for a `subscribe()` to execute before the thing you've subscribed to resolves.  It sounds like you have two components at play--a parent and child--but have only shared code for one of them.  Can you create a MVP that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @JeffryHouser Added more code, hopefully this clarifies the question.

Comment: There is too much irrelevant code here, so it's hard to follow. You should do a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. But can't you just `pipe(filter(data => !!data))` to filter out null values?

Comment: @ritaj I am not trying to filter out `null` values, I am trying to have the pipe _wait_ until the `data` has a value. Currently the data is being emitted before it has a value, if I simply filter then it will not emit anything.
Basically this line should wait on the data:
`switchMap(() => this.data)`

Comment: Actually @ritaj comment, is your answer for making an observable wait till it has a non-null value. You stream wont proceed until data is not null.

Comment: If it will not emit anything when you filter out null values then all of the emitted values are null.